Migrate Angular Project from v16 to v17
As part of the migration, I tried to perform the next command, ng generate @angular/core:standalone, in order to migrating to Standalone components.
After performing that command, most of the migrated components gets the standalone property without the imports property.
Any idea why it doesn't gets the imports property with the necessary dependencies?
Thanks in advance.
